# interactive curve editor in OS X Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, drawing, curve

I am aiming to implement an editable spline or bezier curve for a GUI component in Cocoa OS X 10.6. The functionality could be along the line of the ichart RapahelJS demo http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html or a typical "illustrator-type" handle on the curve points. Exact specification of the curve is somewhat malleable and can conform to what is available/simpler to implement.

So I am hoping to find a library or component that provides a solid basis, with the standard Cocoa patterns applied. I've looked at Core Plot, which seems great to actually plot data, but apparently does not offer interactive methods to modify a data array.

Am I missing something or must such a thing (including hit tests) be implemented from scratch in an NSView? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to check out [DrawKit](https://github.com/DrawKit/DrawKit) by Graham Cox. It's an extremely sophisticated framework and the sample app is amazing.

Comment: Link seems to be dead, can you provide the updated link?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Bezier path editor provided "free" as part of AppKit. Dave DeLong and I have been working on a bezier curve editor app called BezierBuilder which is available [at GitHub](https://github.com/davedelong/BezierBuilder). You may be able to pull out the `BezierView` class and some of its dependencies.

I wouldn't say the app's done by any stretch of the imagination; there are certainly things you'll want to change if you're integrating it into your own app. But it's a start, anyway.

Comment: This looks great! As you say i'll need to add some constraints but it will give me a good start. Any license attached to that? Thanks.

Comment: It's licensed under the MIT license, so it's available for commercial use, requiring attribution.

Comment: Link seems to be dead, can you provide the updated link?